# Python Не могу понять как написать код для того, чтобы создавалась матрица, значения которые я сама вводила с клавиатуры

Tags: python, массивы, клавиатура

```
N = input('Enter count of rows: ')
M = input('Enter count of columns: ')


choose = input('Choose, how do you want to work with matrix: 1(random), 2(from file) or 3(from console)')

#это отрывок кода 
elif choose == 3: 
    matrix = []
    for i in xrange(N):
      for j in xrange(M):
         matrix[i,j] = input('Elements')
         print matrix
```

Comment: Точнее Вы хотите  вручную устанавливать  кол-во  столбцов и строк? Или все же   чтобы выводило ваши значения в  ячейках матрицы?

Comment: Почитайте про многомерные списки. ``matrix[i,j]`` - неправильная нотация.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вы неправильно инициализируете матрицу - размерность неправильная, размеры не известны.

Создать матрицу размером MxN можно таким способом:

```
matrix = [[0]*M for n in range(N)]
```

И заменить строчку

`matrix[i,j] = input('Elements')`

на

`matrix[i][j] = input('Elements')`

Теперь будет работать.